Firebase Realtime Database .info/connected listener always says "false." (Flutter)
In a Flutter/Firebase app, I am trying to have a way of tracking whether users are "online" or not (for purposes of having a directory filterable by "is Online", for exmaple).
At the point in the app where the uid becomes known, I added this:
void _setUpPresenceListener(String uid) async {

  // *** Un-used Realtime Database reference to keep the connection alive
  DatabaseReference userStatusRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('status/$uid');

  // Reference to the .info/connected node in Realtime Database
  DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(".info/connected");

  // Firestore reference to the users_presence collection
  DocumentReference presenceRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users_presence').doc(uid);

  // Listen for connection state changes
  connectedRef.onValue.listen((event) async {
    final bool isConnected = event.snapshot.value as bool? ?? false;
    
    // ***
    print("&&& - val: ${event.snapshot.value.toString()}");

    // If connected, set isOnline to true in Firestore
    if (isConnected) {
      
       await presenceRef.set({
      'isOnline': true,
      'lastChanged': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    } else {
      // When disconnected, set isOnline to false
      await presenceRef.set({
        'isOnline': false,
        'lastChanged': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    }
  });
}

This resulted in the firestore data field always being set to false, so I investigated/troubleshooted(?) by adding the parts marked *** which further verified the issue -- printed value is explicit 'false'
Important points:

Security Rules are not an issue since the field is being written to successfully.
I am testing with an android emulator.
I am not using realtime database for any other purpose in the app.

Is there some other pre-requisite to this listener refecting an accurate connection state?
I was considering whether the reason may be that I am not using realtime database for anything else... and so maybe .info/... is never initialized to anything meaningful because of this?

I expect the onValue to initially fire with false and then later with true. Can you edit your question to show the complete output of the print("&&& - val: ${event.snapshot.value.toString()}"); statement?

I re-tested on a different (public wifi) network and now it works as expected (false, then true like you said).  I was getting false (always... or perhaps false initially then no updates) last night when tethered to iphone personal hotspot. So I'm going to conclude it is working as designed.  Thanks for your clarification!  I'm not sure whether to delete the question or leave it here in case someone else runs into the same situation.

I re-tested again with the previous connection setup (iphone hotspot) and it still works as expected so I have no explanation for why it was not working before.

No need to delete the question, but I am gonna vote to close it as ephemeral/not reproducible.
